# how can i calculate if a location is inside 3d cube

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, location, cube

I'm looking for a way to calculate if a location is inside a cube with rotation.

The information I have the location **(x,y,z)**, rotation **(x,y,z)** and the size **(x,y,z)**.
I use Javascript for this, I have tried the same way as its done in Minecraft plugins but it doesn`t include rotation then:

```
x >= min.x && 
x <= max.x && 
y >= min.y && 
y <= max.y && 
z >= min.z && 
z <= max.z
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this for a game by any chance? If so you'll find great help over at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. This is still a great question over here too.

Comment: Yes it is, ll post i there too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you already have a transform for your cuboid that includes positioning, scaling, and rotation. You can use this transform (more specifically, its inverse) to transform any point into the cuboid's local coordinate system. And there, it is very easy to check if the point is inside the cube.

I'll make a few assumptions here. If they don't match your scenario exactly, you need to modify the approach slightly. But the principle stays the same. I will assume that the standard cube is axis-aligned and between `(0, 0, 0)` and `(1, 1, 1)`. I further assume that that the position references the lower corner. Then, you calculate the overall transform (which you most likely already have) as:

```
T = translate(position) * rotation * scale(size)
```

If we need to find out if a point `p` is inside the cube, transform it with the inverse of `T`:

```
pInLocalSpace = inverse(T) * p
```

And finally check if this is in the standard cube:

```
if(pInLocalSpace.x >= 0 && pInLocalSpace.x <= 1
   && pInLocalSpace.y >= 0 && pInLocalSpace.y <= 1
   && pInLocalSpace.z >= 0 && pInLocalSpace.z <= 1)
    ; //point is inside the cube
else
    ; //point is outside of the cube
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply,
if i do it like this, it will check it like the red box:
http://prntscr.com/koe1d4
not the leaning faces

Comment: Your transform seems to be missing the rotation then.